# How can I make a better unsupervised text classifier model? Is POS tagging part of Machine Learning and Data science?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, data-science-model, text-classification

I have got complaints data, which is not good, and often contains less than 3 words in every complaint (sometimes so short that only one word of them makes sense). The objective is to find what's trending in these complaints i.e. what people are complaining about.

I tried LDA/NMF and other topic modeling techniques but it's not performing well and mixing up different complaints in one. Also, there is no way to monitor these techniques in Production and monitor the performance (what if new types of complaints start coming in the future and the classes start mixing up? I can not fix the number of classes in LDA in production.). To add, LDA/NMF models are computationally expensive.

I built a system to identify Verbs and Nouns as keywords (using texthero - off course after extensive cleaning and lemmatization) and make classes of every complaint being received. Like 100 complaints being received are "delivery" related, another 50 are "quality" related, etc. So far, this system seems to have performed the best, and without any misclassification (obviously).
Now I have two questions:

1. Is POS tagging part of Data Science and Machine learning? I am in a Data science role and how can I justify this work?
2. Is there anything else that I can try given such a dataset?

Comment: To answer your first question, Yes it is a part of ML and DS. To justify it, you could work on an online form of model deployment where the model improves to exposure to more data. For your second question, could you go for LSTM and transformers? Just a guess.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't understand everything.
1. In POS tagging, I don't have any model as such whose performance I can monitor. It uses a pre-trained model for POS tagging which I use as such for POS Tagging and make output out of it. 
2. LSTM and transformers for unsupervised ML? I doubt how it will perform with single worded complaints. Could you perform any link?

Comment: Oh okay, Sorry about that then, I feel you will have to wait for the second answer!

Comment: Are you aware about word embeddings like word2vec and BERT? Your best shot might be to convert the words into vectors using these transfer learning based embeddings and then clustering them using k-means or other clustering techniques.

Comment: @tomar__ Thanks for your reply. But there are problems here. First, there is no way to determine the number of clusters. If I knew that I can logically automate this in production to cluster data daily. Earlier I have tried clustering earlier and encountered that words in a cluster didn't make sense.

Comment: To the point on the number of clusters, there are clustering techniques in which you don't have to specify that (eg. DBSCAN) but instead specify a "density" parameter.
On the second point of clusters not making sense, when you use better embedding models, you cluster those embeddings, the results will end up much better.